# Find geographic data on languages of Russia

Tags: data, russia

Does anyone have any ideas for where I can get data on the number or percentage of speakers of a given language in the Russian Federation at some geographic level smaller than federal subject?

Preferably, the data should come from the 2010 census.

Comment: Do you want free data?

Comment: As @nmtoken hints, if you want free data you are better off posting this question on [OpenData SE.](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that this was the right topic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these maps can help you
https://www.ethnologue.com/language/rus

Do you speak russian? The english version of census website dont have much information http://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/m-sotrudn/eng_site/sensus.html